# Any reason as to why nothing shows in my textbox when this code runs?

Tags: vb.net

works well with the combobox and shows whats in column one of excel but nothing shows in the textbox that's in column 2 in excel...

my code specific for combobox:

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim iStartedRow As Integer
    Dim ITotalRows As Integer

    ITotalRows = ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("a1").Currentregion.Rows.Count

    For iStartedRow = 2 To ITotalRows
        If Me.ComboBox1.Text = COVIDWorksheet.Cells(iStartedRow, 1).text Then
            Me.TextBox1.Text = COVIDWorksheet.Cells(iStartedRow, 2).text

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Debug the code. That's why VS has a debugger. Set a breakpoint and step through the code and you'll see what the problem is.

Comment: Well there are two possible answers to you question.  Either ITotalRows is not what you expect or ComboBox1 doesn’t equal the value in you’re testing against from your spread sheet.  As @jmcilhinney says, a little debugging will answer it.  Remember string equality is case sensitive and includes white space.  Trim and Upper both sides of the if condition maybe